# Sitecore redirects for login page using hostname

Tags: azure, paas, identity-server

We have a sitecore instance (xp0 for now) with an identity server. They are deployed to azure and belong to a private vnet.

Access to nodes is done through the application gateway. But because of those internal sitecore redirects I cant find the way to fix it:

For example:

1. app gw url is "https://my-sitecore.**test.com**", identity server route is "https://my-sitecore.**test.com**/sitecore-identity".
2. I navigate to "https://my-sitecore.**test.com**/sitecore"
3. It redirects to "https://my-sitecore.**azurewebsites.net**/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad?sc_lang=en" and then to "/externallogin"
4. Then it redirects to "https://my-sitecore-identity.**azurewebsites.net**/connect/authorize?client_id=...."

But it exposes all of those urls, and the plan is to keep them internal, only accessing the app from application gateway.

Is there a way to achieve it, or only option is not use the application gateway at all?

Comment: Is it overkill to use application gateway for Sitecore CM ? and moreover you mentioned its is a private vnet

Comment: I will suggest use azure traffic manager or IP whitelisting to keep everything you want internal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for our design we want to use App GW.

Answer (score 2):

Fond a way to make it work!

First of all - couple of assumptions:

1. For simplicity I am using xp0 topology;
2. You are using azure;
3. In azure you have a DNS zone for your domain (test.com in my example)

Now, the solution is actually quite simple!

In the DNS Zone for test.com you create 4 records:

1. A-record for **my-sitecore** pointing to the public ip of the application gateway
2. A-record for **my-sitecore-identity** pointing to the public ip of the application gateway
3. TXT-record for **awverify.my-sitecore** with a value of **my-sitecore.azurewebsites.net**
4. TXT-record for **awverify.my-sitecore-identity** with a value of **my-sitecore-identity.azurewebsites.net**

Next, to your applications you assign custom domains (my-sitecore.text.com for my-sitecore.azurewebsites.net and my-sitecore-identity.test.com for my-sitecore-identity.azurewebsites.net)

Getting to AppGW setup:

- 2 listeners that listen to specific hosts (my-sitecore.test.com and my-sitecore-identity.test.com)
- 2 backends for our apps (my-sitecore.azurewebsites.net and my-sitecore-identity.azurewebsites.net)
- 2 http settings. Important bit here is to set "Override host name" property to be exact the same as listener host name
- 2 probes (usual stuff) that will try to hit "/".

Cool! Now the final step to make is to complete the identity setup. Enable `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` config and set `identityServerAuthority` to `https://y-sitecore-identity.test.com`. Plus all the other setup of identity server with secrets etc.

Phew! But after that - all the redirects worked fine for me!
Hope this will help someone or maybe I`ll forget how it was working and will stumble on this answer sometime later :)

Comment: When you say 'set "Override host name" property to be exact the same as listener host name', can I confirm this means:
Select 'Override with new host name' to true, and using the 'Override with specific domain name' option? (Not 'Pick host name from back target'?)
And then, entering the domains 'my-sitecore.test.com' and 'my-sitecore-identity.test.com' for the respective HTTP Settings items?