# Identity Server not redirecting to Azure Frontdoor URL

Tags: azure, paas, identity-server

We are implementing URL hardening in Azure PaaS. We have added Azure front door urls to CM app. We have updated

> Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config

on CM server with new url for identity server and

> Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml

on identity server with the new urls for Sitecore CM. But still the identity server redirects back to the old CM server url only and not to the Azure front door url for CM. Any inputs on what are we missing here?

Comment: Are you trying to implement Azure AD login integration ?

Comment: No, we are not implementing Azure AD login integration.We are simply trying to redirect from Identity server to Azure front door url instead of CM url after login.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the problem. AFD url simply forwards request to the Sitecore CM webapp url. This means identity server receives request from Sitecore CM URL and not AFD url (even though we see AFD url in browser). So after user gets logged in, identity server redirects user back to Sitecore CM url only and not to AFD url. To fix this, we have added custom domain to Sitecore CM webapp instead of AFD url.

Comment: Hi, can you expand on your solution a little? As I read it, you ended up not using AFD? Or have you used the same custom domain name for both the AFD frontend URL and the app service? I can't see how that would work.

Comment: Ah just found this answer which sounds similar: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24177/sitecore-redirects-for-login-page-using-hostname?rq=1
I think the missing part of the puzzle for me was overriding the host header in the AFD backend.